# How to get histogram data from a 2D NumPy array?

Tags: python, numpy

Can `numpy.histogram()` process a 2D NumPy array? I can't seem to get it to work? In the example below, I am expecting the `numpy.histogram()` function to return a 3x2 where the 2 denotes a tuple with 2 1D numpy array of size 20 contain the necessary count and bins data, respectively.

**Example:**

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from numpy.random import default_rng
>>> from scipy.stats import norm
>>> rg = default_rng()
>>> a = norm.rvs( size=(3, 100), random_state=rg )
>>> np.histogram( a, bins=20 )
(array([ 2,  2,  4,  6, 10, 11, 15, 19, 37, 26, 25, 28, 27, 29, 21, 22,  5,
        5,  3,  3]), array([-2.736423  , -2.47271089, -2.20899879, -1.94528668, -1.68157457,
       -1.41786247, -1.15415036, -0.89043825, -0.62672615, -0.36301404,
       -0.09930193,  0.16441017,  0.42812228,  0.69183439,  0.95554649,
        1.2192586 ,  1.48297071,  1.74668281,  2.01039492,  2.27410703,
        2.53781913]))
>>> np.histogram( a.T, bins=20 )
(array([ 2,  2,  4,  6, 10, 11, 15, 19, 37, 26, 25, 28, 27, 29, 21, 22,  5,
        5,  3,  3]), array([-2.736423  , -2.47271089, -2.20899879, -1.94528668, -1.68157457,
       -1.41786247, -1.15415036, -0.89043825, -0.62672615, -0.36301404,
       -0.09930193,  0.16441017,  0.42812228,  0.69183439,  0.95554649,
        1.2192586 ,  1.48297071,  1.74668281,  2.01039492,  2.27410703,
        2.53781913]))
```

**Edit:**

I am trying the `histrogramdd()` as suggested by @DavidHoffman. The `H` result looks wrong. I am expecting 3 rows of results but have gotten 6 rows. `edges` looks correct. What am I doing wrong?

```
>>> bins = np.linspace(np.array([-3,-3,-3]),  np.array([3,3,3]), num=7, axis=1 )
>>> bins
array([[-3., -2., -1.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.],
       [-3., -2., -1.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.],
       [-3., -2., -1.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.]])
>>> H, edges = np.histogramdd(a.T, bins=bins)
>>> H
array([[[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 2., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0.],
        [0., 2., 0., 1., 1., 0.],
        [0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 2., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 4., 7., 2., 0.],
        [1., 3., 5., 6., 4., 1.],
        [2., 1., 0., 2., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., 3., 1., 0.],
        [1., 2., 2., 3., 1., 0.],
        [1., 2., 4., 1., 3., 0.],
        [0., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 5., 2., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]],

       [[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]]])
>>> edges
[array([-3., -2., -1.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.]), array([-3., -2., -1.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.]), array([-3., -2., -1.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.])]
>>>
```

The results should be similar to results from a for-loop approach (mentioned by @MateenUlhaq).

```
>>> bins = np.linspace( -3, 3, num=7 )
>>> bins
array([-3., -2., -1.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.])
>>> for i in a:
    np.histogram( i, bins=bins )

    
(array([ 5, 10, 41, 32, 10,  2]), array([-3., -2., -1.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.]))
(array([ 3, 10, 37, 37, 11,  2]), array([-3., -2., -1.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.]))
(array([ 5, 17, 26, 33, 18,  1]), array([-3., -2., -1.,  0.,  1.,  2.,  3.]))
```

Comment: Assuming you want to process each row of your 2D data individually... A quick look at the [source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.19.0/numpy/lib/histograms.py#L677-L928) says probably not. A quick look at the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) says *"a: Input data. The histogram is computed over the flattened array."*, which means certainly not.

Comment: I think you'll have to just for loop over your data manually.

Comment: Check out [histogramdd](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogramdd.html)

Comment: @MateenUlhaq Thanks. I know a for-loop approach works. Still, I was hoping NumPy has a quicker built-in function to do the job. Trying histogramdd() but encountered a problem.

Comment: @DavidHoffman My result from `histogramdd()` looks wrong. Can you advise me on how to correct my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible way to avoid a for loop would consist in defining a wrapper for `np.histogram()`:

```py
def wrapper(arr):
    h, _ = np.histogram(arr, bins=np.linspace(-3, 3, num=7))
    return h
```

and passing that wrapper function to [`np.apply_along_axis()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html):

```py
h = np.apply_along_axis(wrapper, 1, a)
```

#### Demo

```py
In [50]: for row in a:
    ...:     h_row, _ = np.histogram(row, bins=np.linspace(-3, 3, num=7))
    ...:     print(h_row)
[ 1 17 38 28 11  4]
[ 1 16 32 35 15  1]
[ 2 11 37 33 16  1]

In [51]: np.apply_along_axis(wrapper, 1, a)
Out[51]: 
array([[ 1, 17, 38, 28, 11,  4],
       [ 1, 16, 32, 35, 15,  1],
       [ 2, 11, 37, 33, 16,  1]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: Thanks. This solution is great. Can your approach work when the value of `bins` is not constant, i.e. different `bins` values are to be used to process each row of `a`?

Comment: Certainly yes, as long as you define the value of `bins` (as a function of `arr`, for example) inside the `wrapper` function.